# Angular JS animating on page load with delay

Tags: angularjs, css-animations

I'm trying to animate the logo on my app home screen so after 2 seconds the logo fades in and begins a looped animation after the fade is complete to bob up and down.

I've thought of adding a timeout in the controller like this:

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.animationClass = 'animateOn';
});
```

And then trigger the animation when the class is added to the dom.

However I think it may be best to put this animation delay code in a directive as it will separate the code and make it reusable.

I just wondered if there's an easier way of doing this as I'm new to animating with Angular JS.

EDIT:

I've made a directive to add a class after a delay. This works great, but is there an easier alternative? See below:

```
.directive('animationDelay', function($animate,$timeout) {
    return function(scope, elem, attr) {
        $timeout(function() {
            $animate.addClass(elem, 'my-animate');
        }, attr.animationDelay);
    };
});
```

Called by using:

```
<img animation-delay="3000" id="mainLogo" src="img/logo.svg" class="homeLogo" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 syntax provides a property to delay an animation, **animation-delay**

You can set the delay to the amount you want, declare the style in a class, and assign the class to the element. You can use the same 'my-animate' class and include the animation delay there [More info](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-delay.asp)

If you want to display the effect after an element appears on screen with ng-show, angular has a library for animations that will come handy, [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate)

Comment: I did try using the animation-delay CSS property, but this did not work for custom transitions. The element was showing on screen before the animation happened. You can't manually add a delay to the ng-show either to hook into ngAnimate so that's why I thought of using the directive